# I have a singelchildscrollview with a debounces option at end of screen when the keyboard popsup it hides the filtered list how to fix it

Tags: flutter, keyboard, singlechildscrollview

[It dose not show the filtered options[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUzfL.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am not able to add images as I am a new member